# Touch gestures on canvas while using VoiceOver

Tags: ios, accessibility, capacitor, voiceover

I'm working on a Capacitor HTML & JS web App and I'm having an hard time with tests while having VoiceOver on iPhone.
I have a page where a canvas is shown, and the user can interact with touch events on the canvas to emit sounds.

The thing is, if I do touch events on the canvas, VoiceOver just change the focus on other focusable elements on the view. No luck even with forcing my canvas to be recognised as a focusable element with `tabindex="0"`.
Touches are just changing focus between elements.

Do you have any idea on what I can do to make touch behaviour working as when VoiceOver is disabled?

I expect VoiceOver to not change the behaviour of my web page: I suggest that might be some native or (better) a Capacitor function to tell VoiceOver to avoid this behaviour and keep things as they are.

Comment: I'm assuming you understand how VoiceOver works. That touching an element just makes it the "active" VoiceOver element. If you want to interact with that element, you then have to double tap (anywhere on the screen). Are you able to tap an element in your canvas and have the VoiceOver focus border drawn around it? If so, does your sound play when you double tap?

Comment: I'm able to make the canvas recognisable by voice over, using a title and/or tabindex="0". Anyway, VoiceOver just reads the title and I cannot hear sounds when I touch stuff INSIDE the canvas. It is like the canvas is not treated really as an interactive element. I'm explaining better: that canvas acts like it is a "game", it has some events for touches on specific elements ON the canvas. If that happens, sounds/vibrations are executed. But VoiceOver just does not let me interact with that as I can when it's disabled.

Comment: In a native app, you could use a direct touch component. This would completely disable VoiceOver gestures as long as the focus is in the component. It works best when it's full screen since any touch outside of the component moves the focus elsewhere. However, I don't know if such a concept exists on a web page, I guess not.

Comment: @QuentinC I think you're referring to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/4161973-accessibilitydirecttouchoptions?language=objc and it does look exactly what I need, although it is still on beta, right?

Comment: I'm not an apple developer so I can't tell you exactly, but it isn't new. It exists since a few years already. Direct touch areas are often used by accessible games. It works great but, of course, you must manually make VO to speak and/or provide audio feedback. Otherwise it's a blackhole totally inaccessible.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve may not be possible in a web-based app. What a native app would use is the `allowsDirectInteraction` trait, which essentially allows VoiceOver users to interact with the UI element directly, bypassing VoiceOver's own gesture navigation model. It's used to allow VoiceOver users to interact with handwriting features, signature boxes, musical apps like a piano. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620172-allowsdirectinteraction

Comment: VoiceOver has a "pass-thru" gesture that may work here. You double-tap on the touchscreen with one finger but hold the second tap down until you hear an audio prompt (three tones) indicating that the gesture will now bypass VoiceOver's gesture navigation model. As soon as you lift your finger off the screen, it goes back to VoiceOver's usual navigation mode. It can be used to have finer control over slider values, for example. It might allow you to interact with your web app.